# Docker container can't reach another container using container name

Tags: docker, kotlin, microservices, docker-container, spring-webclient

I have 2 Docker containers running in the same network and I want 1 of them to call another via spring Webclient.
I'm sure they all are in the same network -> *docker network inspect <network_ID>* proves this.
AFAIK I can ping one container from another to check if they can talk to each other by *docker exec -ti attachment-loader-prim ping attachment-loader-sec*
If I run this - I see responses from attachment-loader-sec like `64 bytes from 172.21.0.5: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.220 ms`, which means they can communicate.
When I send Postman request to attachment-loader-prim by its exposed port `localhost:8085`, I expect that after some business logic it calls for attachment-loader-sec via Webclient, but on that step I get a 500 error with such a message:

> "finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused:
> attachment-loader-sec/172.21.0.5:80; nested exception is
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:
> finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused:
> attachment-loader-sec/172.21.0.5:80"

Both attachment-loader-prim and attachment-loader-sec can be accessed separately via postman and both send a response, no problem.
This is my docker-compose:

```
    version: '3'
services:
  attachment-loader-prim:
    container_name: attachment-loader-prim
    build:
      context: ""
    restart: always
    image: attachment-loader:latest
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: 8085
    networks:
      - loader_network
    expose:
      - 8085
    ports:
      - 8005:8005
      - 8085:8085

  attachment-loader-sec:
    container_name: attachment-loader-sec
    build:
      context: ""
    restart: always
    image: attachment-loader:latest
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: 8086
    networks:
      - loader_network
    expose:
      - 8086
    ports:
      - 8006:8005
      - 8086:8086

networks:
  loader_network:
    driver: bridge
```

And this is a Webclient which makes a call:

```
    class RemoteServiceCaller(private val fetcherWebClientBuilder: WebClient.Builder) {

suspend fun getAttachmentsFromRemote(id: String, params: List<Param>, username: String): Result? {

    val client = fetcherWebClientBuilder.build()

    val awaitExchange = client.post()
            .uri("/{id}/attachment", id)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(params)
            .header(usernameHeader, username)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .awaitExchange {
                if (it.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful) {
                    handleSucessCode(it)
                } else it.createExceptionAndAwait().run {
                    LOG.error(this.responseBodyAsString, this)
                    throw ProcessingException(this)
                }
            }

    return awaitExchange
}

private suspend fun handleSucessCode(response: ClientResponse) {
// some not important logic
}
}
```

P.S. BasicUri for Webclient defined as Config Bean like `http://attachment-loader-sec/list`

All my investigations brought me to such problems as:

- Calling container using *localhost* instead of container name
- Containers are not in the same network.

All that seems not relevant for me.

Any ideas will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the default bridge network or did you create one?

Comment: @Paolo I use my own network called 'loader_network'. And Docker network inspect shows that both containers are in my loader_network.

Comment: Your URL is missing the port number, and it's trying to connect to the default port 80.  If you're configuring the secondary service to use port 8086, try `http://attachment-loader-sec:8086/list` instead.

Comment: (Different containers can internally use the same port; I would remove the `SERVER_PORT` configuration and use some fixed default.  That port needs to be included in cross-container calls and to be the second number in `ports:`, but the first `port:` number needs to be unique across the host.  `expose:` does nothing and you can remove it; you can also delete the `networks:` blocks and `container_name:` overrides to use sensible defaults Compose provides for you.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Ok, but if docker provides its own container_name, how I will address it then?

Comment: And thanks for the hint, I added the port to URL, and now I get '404 Not Found from POST http://attachment-loader-sec:8086/list/2513/attachment' but unfortunately no error message provided

Comment: The Compose service name `attachment-loader-sec` can still be used for inter-container DNS regardless of whether or not you specify `container_name:`.

Comment: If you're getting an HTTP 404 error, you're successfully connecting to the other service, but the URL path is wrong.  That's going to be a separate problem from what you're describing here.

Comment: You're right, that's a different problem. I will play with URL, seems like it's wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in calling a service without its port. The url became now `http://attachment-loader-sec:8086/list` and it is correct now. In my case I get 404, which means that my url path is not quite correct, but that is outside of current question